# Powershell Check Versions Of Computer List

Tags: windows, powershell

Have a massive list of machines I need to get the IE version of.

Currently just connecting via remote registry and writing values to a text file, comma delimited for pretty Excel view.

In this list of machines, are some servers and obsolete machines that aren't Windows. I'd like to be able to skip the IE check if not Windows, but echo a Failure, then onto the next machine.

This is currently what I'm doing, but I'm not quite sure if it's done properly. It's still checking IE version for non-windows, instead writing a failure.

(Note, IE6-8 have a different registry key for version, which is why there's the redundant IF)

```
$computernames = Get-Content C:\ps\servers.txt

echo "Server,Status,IE Version;" >> C:\ps\result.txt


foreach ($server in $computernames) {

if (!(Get-Service "Windows Audio" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ))

{

$failure = $server + ",Failure,;"
echo $failure >> C:\ps\result.txt

}

else

{

Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name RemoteRegistry |Start-Service



$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server) 

$IEkey = $reg.OpenSubkey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\') 

If (!$IEKEY) 
    {
    $IEVALUE = '0'  
    }
if ($IEKEY) 
    {

    $IEvalue = $IEkey.GetValue('svcVersion') 
        IF (!$IEVALUE)
        {
        $IEvalue = $IEkey.GetValue('Version') 
        }
    }


$result = $server + ",Success," + $IEvalue + ";"

echo $result >> C:\ps\result.txt

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script looks good, but you are missing the -ComputerName parameter in your first check:

```
if (!(Get-Service "Windows Audio" -ComputerName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ))

{
```

Comment: Doh! x_x. While I just did something a little different, I'm willing to bet that this correction would also make my script work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up doing this a little differently.

Seems to work as expected, posted in case anyone wants to do the same.

```
$computernames = Get-Content C:\ps\servers.txt

echo "Server,Status,IE Version;" >> C:\ps\result.txt


foreach ($server in $computernames) {

Get-Service -ComputerName $server -Name RemoteRegistry -ErrorVariable ERRORFLAG |Start-Service

IF (!$ERRORFLAG) {

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $server) 

$IEkey = $reg.OpenSubkey('SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\') 

If (!$IEKEY) 
    {
    $IEVALUE = '0'  
    }
if ($IEKEY) 
    {

    $IEvalue = $IEkey.GetValue('svcVersion') 
        IF (!$IEVALUE)
        {
        $IEvalue = $IEkey.GetValue('Version') 
        }
    }


$result = $server + ",Success," + $IEvalue + ";"

echo $result >> C:\ps\result.txt
}
ELSE {
$failure = $server + ",Failure,;"
echo $failure >> C:\ps\result.txt}
}
```